# Android Spannable multiple setSpan in one TextView

Tags: android

I'm developing a simple search box in my application, and I want to highlight multiple words in one sentence.

I use [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) to add multiple span in one sentence.
Here the function a wrote

```
private CharSequence highlightText(String text, String query) {
    if (query != null && !query.isEmpty()) {

        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(text);
        ForegroundColorSpan highlightSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);

        String[] queryParts = query.split(" ");
        for (String queryPart : queryParts) {
            int startPos = text.toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(queryPart.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
            int endPos = startPos + queryPart.length();

            if (startPos != -1) {
                Log.d(TAG, "find: '" + queryPart + "' in '" + text + "' (" + startPos + ")");
                spannable.setSpan(highlightSpan, startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
        return spannable;

    } else {
        return text;
    }
}
```

When I cal this function with

```
TextView spannableTest = findViewById(R.id.spannable_test);
spannableTest.setText(highlightText(
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
            "ipsum consect"));
```

I got this logs

```
 D/SPAN: find: 'ipsum' in 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.' (6)
 D/SPAN: find: 'consect' in 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.' (28)
```

But on result screen only the last occurence is realy highlighted

[image: Result image]

Comment: move `ForegroundColorSpan highlightSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);` to `for` loop

Comment: Shouldn't it be `textView.setText(spannableStringBuilder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);` ?

Comment: @pskink this is the right answer ! Thanks

Comment: good, its great it works now

Comment: @pskink Can you write your solution as a answer so i can validate it ?

Comment: oh, feel free to write a self-answer ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@pskink pointed I should move `ForegroundColorSpan highlightSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);` to `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you! Why do we need to do that?

Comment: This saved my day. Never knew Spans should not be reused.

Answer (score 1):

Add this file to your project:**RichTextView.java**

```
package com.outpace.expert.utility;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.RelativeSizeSpan;
import android.text.style.StrikethroughSpan;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.text.style.URLSpan;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Deep Patel on 19-11-16
 */

//.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE); to textView if not work
public class RichTextView extends SpannableString {
    private String syntax;

    public RichTextView(String syntax) {
        super(syntax);
        this.syntax = syntax;
    }

    public RichTextView setTextColor(String word, int color) {
        setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), syntax.indexOf(word), syntax.indexOf(word) + word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return this;
    }

    public RichTextView setSize(String word, float howMuch) {
        setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(howMuch), syntax.indexOf(word), syntax.indexOf(word) + word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return this;
    }

    public RichTextView setStrikeOut(String word) {
        setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), syntax.indexOf(word), syntax.indexOf(word) + word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return this;
    }

    public RichTextView setUrl(String word, String redirectUrl) {
        setSpan(new URLSpan(redirectUrl), syntax.indexOf(word), syntax.indexOf(word) + word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return this;
    }

    public RichTextView setBold(String word) {
        StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
        setSpan(boldSpan, syntax.indexOf(word), syntax.indexOf(word) + word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return this;
    }

    //setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); after or before call
    public RichTextView setClickable(String word, final setOnLinkClickListener listener) {
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onLinkClicked();
                }
            }
        };
        setSpan(clickableSpan, syntax.indexOf(word), syntax.indexOf(word) + word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return this;
    }

    public interface setOnLinkClickListener {
        void onLinkClicked();
    }
}
```

Here is how to use:

```
String data = model.getMessage().replace("{from_name}", model.getFromUser()); // String to display

tvNotificationText.setText(new RichTextView(data)
                    .setBold(model.getFromUser())    // bold 
                    .setTextColor(model.getFromUser(), ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.textPrimary))); // set text color for specific string
```

There are other spanning options available please explore and get the best fit solution!

Happy Coding !!

Comment: I'm sure this is a great solution, but @pskink giving a realy simple solution to my problem.

Comment: okay! Actually I gave this cuz you wanted multiple spanning, i thought you want to go for more than 3 spanning then this might be a useful one